# AWS EC2 WordPress, How Do I force the URL to redirect to HTTPS and force WWW

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, web-config, config

I have a new EC2 Instance on the AWS (Amason Web Services) server. I need to force the URL to always rewrite (redirect) to HTTPS and www in the URL, no matter from which URL they come from.

I'm sure there must be rewrite rules in the apache config, right?

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer, you need to write this into the Apache.conf config file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```